# Write nested Select queries for same table in Zend Framework2

Tags: php, sql-server, zend-framework2

Following is my query

```
SELECT d.[today date], d.mydatediff,d.cc_exp
FROM (
    SELECT GETDATE() AS 'today date',
    cc_exp,
    DATEDIFF(DAY, CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(DAY, -1, DATEADD(MONTH, 1, CONVERT(DATETIME, '1/' + cc_exp, 103)))), GETDATE()) AS mydatediff,
    [customer_member_id]
    FROM [ats].[dbo].[customers]
    WHERE cc_exp IS NOT NULL AND customer_member_id IN ('11111','2222','33333')
) d
WHERE d.mydatediff BETWEEN 30 AND 100
ORDER BY d.mydatediff DESC
```

I tried creating two SQL statments

```
$column = array(
    'dateDiff' => new Expression('DATEDIFF(DAY, CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(DAY, -1, DATEADD(MONTH, 1, CONVERT(DATETIME, \'1/\' + cc_exp, 103)))), GETDATE())'), 
    'cc_exp',
    'customer_member_id'
);
$subselect = $sql->select();

$subselect->from(array('cus' => 'customers'));
$subselect->columns($column);
$where = new Where();
$where->in('customer_member_id', $memberId);
$where->and->isNotNull('cc_exp');
$subselect->where($where);

//$parent select
$select = $sql->select();
$select->from(array($subselect));
$selectColumn = array('cus.customer_member_id', 'cus.cc_exp', 'cus.dateDiff');
$where2 = new Where();
$where->between('cus.dateDiff','30','100');
$select->where($where2);
```

But it gives me an error

> from() expects $table as an array is a single element associative array

Comment: Was my answer helpful? Please upvote if it was, and mark it accepted if it answered your question. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have a number of errors in this code that I can see:

- You're defining the `cus` alias inside the subquery, but then using it in the main query
- You're defining a list of columns for the main query but then not using them
- You're not defining an alias for the subquery results

Try refactoring the code using the same aliases used in the original query, this will make it easier to compare the two. Then I think your main query would have something like this `$select->from(array("d" => $subselect));` which should work.